# node.js module or require.js

Tags: node.js, requirejs

i wonna programming web app and using express.js as webframework. As testing framework i will use mocha and chai.

Node.js support modular programming, i can load module with require like require("mocha"). On frontend i use require.js for organize my codes in module, but this can be use in node.js to. It it better to use require.js in node.js or better to use node.js standard module.

I know that require.js support AMD and testing codes with mocha it can comlicated, because the codes will be load asynchronously.

Node.js require or require.js for module loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) supports `CommonJS` module format.

If you have modules that you want to use both in browser and **node.js**, you can [use **require.js** in **node**](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

Comment: but what is better commonjs or requirejs?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. [tag:require.js] uses function wrapping approach (as explained [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html)) to load modules **asynchronously**. IMO it's designed with browsers in mind. You won't need it in [tag:node.js], unless you're going to write a module for both browsers and **node**.